"The officer did not even give me the dignity of an explanation."

"The officer did not even give me the dignity of an explanation."

I can't tell whether this use of "dignity" is correct. Thoughts?

Where did you see this sentence? The word is used in this sense: a sign or token of respect:
an impertinent question unworthy of the dignity of an answer. {Dictionary.com}

I haven't seen the sentence that I propose anywhere. But I've seen the sentence you cite: "The argument did not warrant the dignity of a response / reply / answer." If that works, wouldn't my proposed sentence work? Or am I falling into the trap of using "dignity" as "respect," which Garner says is wrong?

The "dignity"-related wording that I hear people use most often involves the verb dignify, as in "The officer didn't dignify my request for an explanation with an answer." Most often, however, that wording applies to situations where a request or (especially) accusation is so lacking in merit that the person addressed treats it as being beneath notice: "She chose not to dignify the wild conspiracy theory with a response."

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Related: Should the expression "to treat people with dignity" be,instead "to accord dignity to people"?.

"without even the dignity of  _________" is a formulaic phrase expressing the speaker's sense of having been utterly disrespected, not shown even a modicum of the respect they were due.  What fills the slot is something that would be a shred of respect.

The board denied all such requests without even giving the applicants the dignity of an explanation, just the word DENIED in all capital letters stamped on the application form.

"the dignity of _____" is also a formulaic phrase expressing the idea of "due respect".  What fills the slot is something that would suffice as an expression of respect.

The board denied all such requests but gave each applicant the dignity of a letter explaining  in  detail their reasons for not approving the request. And it wasn't just  a form letter but addressed the specific situation.


Very helpful examples of this use of "dignity." As Edwin mentioned above, this is a somewhat idiomatic use of "dignity," right? Another issue is whether "treat X with dignity" is correct. That phrase might be gaining traction and might now be idiomatic but some (such as Garner) detest it.

@595519 Sorry; I was using the default sense of 'idiomatic', meaning 'as commonly used by Anglophones', not the secondary sense, 'pertaining to idioms'. But here, as Tim points out, there is also at least a fixed-phrase aspect (idioms being fixed phrases with unusual sense of word/s and/or unusual grammar).
